# como guardar datos con comas en mysql con php usando pdo,lo guarda en dos cuando le doy insertar y elimina la coma

Tags: php

```
                $objAdjEmail = new adjuntoEmail();
                //$objAdjEmail = $arrayObjAdjuntos[$indice];
                $objAdjEmail->setUrlArchivo($urlAdjunto);
                $objAdjEmail->setIdCorreo($pcorreo->getId());
                $objAdjEmail->guardar()
```

ejemplo tras,paso quiero guardar eso, lo guarda en dos registro en la bd 
tras
paso

Answer (score 1):

Porque no intentas escapando las comas usando `str_replace`, algo similar a esto:

```
<?php
 $tuVariable = "a,b,c";
 $tuVariable = str_replace(',','\,', $tuVarialbe);
 //Produce: a\,b\,c
?>
```

Espero te resulte.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago través de una función para realizar el insert. Mi funcion es:

```
function insertarBD($tabla,$campos, $valores){
  // Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = dbConnect ();
  // Define an insert query
  $param = explode(",",$campos);
  $parametros = implode(",:",$param);
  $parametros = ":".$parametros;

  $insertSQL ="INSERT INTO " . $tabla . "(" . $campos . ") VALUES (" . $parametros .")";
  $sentencia = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO " . $tabla . "(" . $campos . ") VALUES (" . $parametros .")");
  $arr_length = count($param);
  $parametros1 = explode(",",$parametros);
  $valores1 = explode("|",$valores);
  for($i=0;$i<$arr_length;$i++)
  {
      $sentencia->bindParam($parametros1[$i], $valores1[$i]);
  }
  $sentencia->execute();
  $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
```

Los parametos los paso separados por comas y los valores por pipes (|), y así me funciona

Answer (score 0):

#### Pregunta:

> **¿Cómo insertar (escribir/guardar) datos que contenga comas en una base de datos?**

#### Respuesta:

> **No debería haber ningún problema a la hora de realizar la consulta con [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) siempre que se pasen bien los parámetros.**

### Ejemplo de construcción y uso

> Preparar constantes de configuración de la base de datos, en este caso MySQL

```
define("DRIVER_SQL", "mysql");
define("DATABASE", "tu_base_de_Datos");
define("PORT", "3306");
define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "1234");

define("URI", DRIVER_SQL . ":dbname=" . DATABASE . ";port=" . PORT . ";host=" . HOSTNAME);
```

> Crear clase aplicando patrón singleton que retorne una instancia de PDO.

```
class DB
{
    private static $pdo;

    final private function __construct() 
    {
        // Constructor vacío y privado. 
    }

    function _destructor()
    {
        // Destructor que se encarga de cerrar la conexión y limpiar el puntero de PDO.
        self::$pdo = null;
    }

    private static function connect()
    {
        try 
        {
            if (self::$pdo != null) return self::$pdo;
            self::$pdo = new PDO(URI, USERNAME, PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
            return self::$pdo;
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo($e);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

> Añadir métodos estáticos a la clase que utilicen la instancia PDO.

```
public static function insertUpdateDelete($sql, $parameters)
{
    try 
    {
        $rs = DB::connect()->prepare($sql);
        $rs = $rs->execute($parameters);
        return $rs != null && $rs != 0 ? true : false;
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        print_r($e);
        return null;
    }
}

public static function select($sql, $parameters = null)
{
    try 
    {
        $rs = DB::connect()->prepare($sql);
        $rs->execute($parameters);
        return $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        print_r($e);
       return null;
    }
}
```

> Uso de la clase DB creada. Los parámetros los pasamos en un array.

```
include_once 'DB.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO tabla VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
$params = [ null, "STACK", "OVERFLOW", 8 ];

$rs = DB::insertUpdateDelete($query, $params);

echo $rs === true ? 'INSERT OK' : 'INSERT ERROR';

$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE age > ?;";
$params = [ 5 ];

$filas = DB::select($query, $params);

foreach ($filas as $fila) {
    foreach($fila as $columna) {
        // Hacer algo
    }
}
```